# Syntax error in websocket in Microsoft Edge

Tags: websocket, syntax-error, microsoft-edge

Actually, the problem is the project works fine in localhost running in MS Edge, but not in the live site.

I tried to reproduce this error in localhost. Running the code with breakpoints to exactly to find where the error occurs.

This is the line where error occurred:

```
'wss://' + location.hostname + ':' + location.port + '/websocket/videovisit';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,
         'wss://' + location.hostname + ':' + location.port + '/websocket/videovisit' as far this line is considered in localhost it will set the value as  **'wss://localhost:8080/websocket/videovisit'**,it works fine.
         While in the live site the value will be set as **'wss://www.example.com:/websocket/videovisit'**, this line works fine in chrome, firefox except in edge because of this ":".Avoid this :(colon) in edge browser to eliminate syntax error in web socket.